# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-unittest

I'm running this command:

```
python manage.py test project.apps.app1.tests
```

and it causes this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'

Below is my directory structure. I've also added app1 to my installed apps config.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "manage.py", line 10, in <module> execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 50, in run_from_argv
    super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 71, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 88, in handle
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 146, in run_tests
    suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
    File "/home/username/local/dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 66, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.loadTestsFromName(label)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'
```

Directory structure:

[image]

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I finally figured it out working on another problem. The problem was that my test couldn't find an import.

It looks like you get the above error if your test fails to import. This makes sense because the test suite can't import a broken test. At least I think this is what is going on because I fixed the import within my test file and sure enough it started working.

To validate your test case just try import the test case file in python console.

Example:

```
from project.apps.app1.tests import *
```

Comment: Bad assumption in that message.

Comment: This can also be done from the command line, eliminating the need to open a Python shell: `python -c "from project.apps.app1.tests import *"`

Comment: +1 saved me from confusing error message. The only problem with your suggestion is that you imported **death star** . OK in console for experiments, but in code, always import just the names needed.

Comment: Instead of fearing use of the "**death star**" can't you juse use the `__all__` variable in each file?  And specify a list of class names, functions, and variables to export when using `from package_name.module import *`?  I've had good luck with this pattern.  I understand it takes a bit more time to write up the `__all__` bit at the top of each file.  But importing using "**death star**" seems to work nicely.

Comment: I just had this issue and was really confused.  Thanks for the answer.  Python is not doing the right thing here.  It needs a clearer message.  That being said, I assume your "...import *" is just to check the tests, not meant to be part of the test runner...  I think the latter would be inappropriate.

Comment: This answer can't be accepted although it works. Never import in python with star

Comment: Yep the star was just an example.

Answer (score 39):

Use:

`./manage.py shell`

followed by

`import myapp.tests`

to find the nature of the import error.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, and it seems like this worked for many people.  But, when I opened a python interactive shell using `./manage.py shell` then did either `import myapp.tests` or `from myapp.tests import *` both worked without error.  But, I still get the error described by the OP.

Answer (score 23):

For my case, I need to create an **empty __init__.py** in my `app/tests` folder

Answer (score 6):

Steve Bradshaw's example above works for import errors (thanks Steve).

Other type of errors (e.g. ValueError) may also cause

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'
```

to see what these errors are

```
./manage.py shell
from myapp.tests import SomeTestCase
t = SomeTestCase()
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error as Chris.  I had deleted an old model, then run tests.py, but another file (views.py) was still trying to import the deleted model.

When I took out the now-obsolete import statement, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that all modules that you are using in your script are not broken. By this I mean check spelling in your import statements.

```
# invalid import
from app.model.notification import Notification
# valid import
from app.models.notification import Notification
```

You can test yours modules by executing imports statements in djano's interactive console.

```
$root@13faefes8: python manage.py shell
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information (InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app.model.notification import Notification
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named model.notification
```

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the error "AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'name_of_my_function' " by fixing a circular import reference. My files manage.py and utils.py each had an import statement pointing at each other.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. It turned out to be because I named my module common.py, yet there already was some other common.py module. All I had to do was to rename my module.

Answer (score 1):

According to django document When you [run your tests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests), the default behavior of the test utility is to find all the test cases (that is, subclasses of [unittest.TestCase](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase)) in any file whose name begins with test, automatically build a test suite out of those test cases, and run that suite.

so try this : `python manage.py test tests.py`

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, but checked all the reasons list here, did not fix my problem.

Finally figure it out that, the reason is that the name of one method that imported but not used yet is not correct. Though it is a stupid error, it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while writing a unittest.TestCase.
When I re-typed the same method definition as-is, it seemed to work !

The only change I noticed on PyCharm  was the 'override' icon pop-up the 2nd time, as the setup(self) method needs to override the original method defined in TestCase.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution was just renaming my module.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You mean like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932529/2227743)?