# AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am receiving **AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'a'**.  I don't understand what is wrong with the code. Please advise.

```
class Test():
    def __int__(self):
        self.a = 1

t = Test()
print(t.a)
```

Comment: Its `__init__` not `__int__`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tests'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575073/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-tests)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please go through guidelines before asking - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It should be **init** (short for initialise), not **int** (integer):

```
class Test():
    # here was the fault
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

t = Test()
print(t.a)
# Outputs 1
```

You defined the wrong method